# Is there a way to search specifically for literature reviews which have been written by others on a certain topic?

Tags: google-scholar, literature-search, review-articles

Is there a way to search specifically for literature reviews which have been written by others on a certain topic?

I’d like the search to either return literature reviews on their own or contained within articles. At present, when I do a Google Scholar search for literature reviews it returns a list of articles containing the term “literature review” which clearly isn’t what I want.

The reason I’m asking is because I’m looking to get an overview of the research that has taken place in a certain area.

Comment: Surely relevant papers will contain a relevant literature review?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Web of Science. After you've searched for the topic, look on the left and refine by article type -> review.

Less effectively, but still workable, include the word "review" in your Google Scholar search. Many review articles will use that word in either the title or the abstract ("In this paper we review ...").

Comment: It's worth noting that your second suggestion won't be workable in all fields. In e.g. physics it will pick up a simply unmanageable number of papers published in the Physical Review family of journals, and also a lot of references to such papers.